# What happens if I hide the parent view that contains an UIActivityIndicatorView attached? Does the activity indicator still spin and take cycles?

Tags: ios, show-hide, uiactivityindicatorview

In my app I attach an UIActivityIndicatorView to a larger view that covers the entire app to prevent users from pressing buttons while I save data to the cloud. When I save, I un-hide the view containing the activity indicator. When the save is complete and data is replicated, I hide the view containing the activity indicator.

Is the activity indicator still taking cycles event though I have hidden the parent view? As a best practice should we always call -stopAnimating?

Answer (score 0):

It might be good to use this property:

```
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
```

Then, all you have to do is stop and start animation.  The activityIndicator will hide on its own.

So if you have a hidden / unhidden system, just switch it with a startAnimations / stopAnimations system

Comment: This would work. However, my activity indicator is a subview of a parent view that covers the whole screen. I would need to stop the activity indicator and hide the parent view. Hence my original question, if I just hide the parent view, is the activity indicator still animating and taking cycles?